# I have difference in check In Luggage with Lufthansa and collaboration with SwissAir

Tags: luggage, lufthansa, swiss

I have a question regarding booking with Lufthansa/SwissAir:

I have booked a check in baggage of 23 Kg with Lufthansa 
[image]

however the luggage is not showing on the SwissAir Ticket. 
[image]

What should I do?

I have tried to contact both companies without success..

The ticket was bought through google flight, it was a 2 flight trip to italy, the first flight is swiss air and the connecting flight is lufthansa.

Comment: Please provide more information. There are too many possible situations. You could post the different confirmations here, but make sure to leave out any booking reference or ticket number.

Comment: Where did you buy the tickets?

Comment: Google flight does not sell tickets. It will link you to another site. So which site did you buy your ticket from?

Comment: My understanding is that you buy tickets from Lufthansa via Google Flights.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/48MZg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had my flight a couple of days ago. for anyone having this problem sometimes swiss air system does not update, but if you have bought the checkin luggage everything should be fine. just go to the airport with the copy of the mail that confirm your purchase of the luggage.

Additional info since I was not clear enough: I have bought the tickets through luftansa.